# Why did MS get rid of BindableBase in the new Windows Store app templates?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In the new VS 2013 app templates, like Grid, I don't see a BindableBase class anymore.
WHy did they change it, and what is better about the new approach they are using?

I'm not understanding yet the new template structure.

Comment: I can ask them tomorrow because I sure do miss it as well. It made it so easy to start a [minimalistic mvvm](http://blog.onedevjob.com/2012/08/27/minimalistic-mvvm-for-windows-runtime-xaml-platform-development-with-c/) project...

Fortunately it's easy to recreate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is it was taken away because it wasn't used by the templates and thus it wasn't necessary to include to force anyone into specific class design.

If you miss it - you can use [my code snippets](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1192076/My%20Code%20Snippets.zip) to easily create one:

1. Put my snippets in %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets
2. Type vm[tab] or vm[Esc][Tab] if you have ReSharper installed to drop the full bindable base snippet in your app. You could also use a bb snippet for just the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation. Once you find a version you like - you can also export it to a VS item template (VS File menu).